# Mixing YAML and Markdown

Tags: yaml, markdown

I am using YAML quite a bit, but I want to be able to include links. I tried Markdown links in a YAML file, but the entire punctuation is displayed.  I tried YAML formatting in a Markdown file, but there is no indentation in the YAML lines. I am open to a paid program, but I'd rather try an open source program first.  Thank you.

I did a number of browser searches, and I experimented with some things I found.

Answer (score 6):

A link is just a data point. YAML is a data serialization format. You can of course write

```yaml
url: https://example.com
```

and YAML will parse it as mapping that contains a URL (the URL will be most likely a string unless you write a custom constructor). YAML doesn't *render* or *display* anything; applications that use YAML might allow you to process YAML input to displayed output, but that would be a question about that specific application and cannot be answered generally for YAML.

If you want to include YAML in a Markdown file and render it with indentation, use a code block, e.g.

````markdown
```yaml
some:
  yaml: data
```
````

Comment: > _If you want to include YAML in a Markdown file and render it with indentation, use a code block..._

Yes, this is exactly the answer I was looking for.  The YAML code block renders the Markdown links without the punctuation marks.  Thank you, flyx.